# how can i get user id in an apollo resolver when using meteor

Tags: meteor, apollo

How can i get user id in an apollo resolver when using meteor as backend?
This could be very powerful if i can resolve some user bound properties
I have tried with a resolver like this

```
Query: {        
    eventDetail(obj, {_id}, {user}) {
        // query logic
    }
},
// resolve record
Event: {  
    state: Meteor.bindEnvironment((record) => {
        return UserEventStates.findOne({eventId: record._id, createdBy: Meteor.userId()}) || {};
    })
},
Mutation: {
    // other mutation queries
}
```

but I got this error

```
Exception in callback of async function: Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls or publications.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Meteor.userId()`, add `user` to context and use `user._id`:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/meteor#Server

Comment: you can do it in the query/mutation operation, but here im resolving the record's property, where i have only the info of record.

Comment: currently i've resolved it by injecting the user id into the record during query, ugly solution, but it works, i hope there is a better way to do this

Comment: The third argument to all resolvers should be the context, including your record's property.